# Replace Date format in a string provided using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, date

I am trying to change a string which may have a date inside e.g.

```
"This is the test string with 22/12/2012. 23/12/12 could anywhere in the string"
```

I need to change above string so that date are in the format d-m-y i.e.

```
"This is the test string with 22-12-2012. 23-12-12 could appear anywhere in the string"
```

**EDIT:**
Please note that the date will could changed in terms of years i.e. 2012 or 12 could be used at time i.e 20/06/2012, 20/06/12. Only year could be 2 or 4 digits, rest will be same.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Will date always be in `dd/mm/yy` format?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @anubhava: please check my edit. Date will be in the same format except year could 2 or 4 digits.

Comment: @GhazanfarMir: Thanks, I answered it below, check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use preg_replace like this:

```
$repl = preg_replace('~(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2,4})~', '$1-$2-$3', $str);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/7HDNZa

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace("/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2,4})/", "$1-$2-$3", $string);
```

The regex will find 3 lots of 2 numbers (or 2x2 + 1x4) separated by /'s and replace them with the same numbers separated by -'s.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
preg_replace('~\b([0-2]?[1-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?=(?:\d\d|\d{4})\b)~', '$1-$2-', $str);
```

Should match valid dates only. Does match dates where the prefix `0` is not present, e.g. `4/16/13` if this is not desierable, remove the two first question marks (in `[0-2]?` and `0?`)